# Converting yearmon column to last date of the month in R

Tags: r, zoo, lubridate

I have a data frame (df) like the following:

```
Date        Arrivals

2014-07      100
2014-08      150
2014-09      200
```

I know that I can convert the yearmon dates to the first date of each month as follows:

```
df$Date <- as.POSIXct(paste0(as.character(df[,1]),"-01"), format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

However, given that my data is not available until the end of the month I want to index it to the end rather than the beginning, and I cannot figure it out. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the `Date` variable is an actual `yearmon` class vector, from the **zoo** package, the `as.Date.yearmon` method can do what you want via its argument `frac`.

Using your data, and assuming that the `Date` was originally a character vector

```
library("zoo")
df <- data.frame(Date = c("2014-07", "2014-08", "2014-09"),
                 Arrivals = c(100, 150, 200))
```

I convert this to a `yearmon` vector:

```
df <- transform(df, Date2 = as.yearmon(Date))
```

Assuming this is what you have, then you can achieve what you want using `as.Date()` with `frac = 1`:

```
df <- transform(df, Date3 = as.Date(Date2, frac = 1))
```

which gives:

```
> df
     Date Arrivals    Date2      Date3
1 2014-07      100 Jul 2014 2014-07-31
2 2014-08      150 Aug 2014 2014-08-31
3 2014-09      200 Sep 2014 2014-09-30
```

That shows the individual steps. If you only want the final `Date` this is a one-liner

```
## assuming `Date` is a `yearmon` object
df <- transform(df, Date = as.Date(Date, frac = 1))
## or if not a `yearmon`
df <- transform(df, Date = as.Date(as.yearmon(Date), frac = 1))
```

The argument `frac` in the fraction of the month to assign to the resulting dates when converting from `yearmon` objects to `Date` objects. Hence, to get the first day of the month, rather than convert to a character and paste on `"-01"` as your Question showed, it's better to coerce to a `Date` object with `frac = 0`.

If the `Date` in your `df` is not a `yearmon` class object, then you can solve your problem by converting it to one and then using the `as.Date()` method as described above.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a way to do it using the zoo package.

R code:

```
library(zoo)
df
#      Date Arrivals
# 1 2014-07      100
# 2 2014-08      150
# 3 2014-09      200

df$Date <- as.Date(as.yearmon(df$Date), frac = 1)

# output
#         Date Arrivals
# 1 2014-07-31      100
# 2 2014-08-31      150
# 3 2014-09-30      200
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `lubridate`, you can add a month and subtract a day to get the last day of the month:

```
library(lubridate)

ymd(paste0(df$Date, '-01')) + months(1) - days(1)
# [1] "2014-07-31" "2014-08-31" "2014-09-30"
```